# На чем сделать заказ билетов для сайта?

Tags: javascript, framework

[image: пример]
С помощью чего лучше всего создать подобный скрипт? Какой фреймворк посоветуете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнем с того, что любой фреймворк из современных-популярных (Angular, React, Vue) - отлично подойдут для решения данной задачи. Тут надо смотреть со стороны - на чем удобном Вам делать данное решение. Удобно и тянете знаниями vanilla js (он же pure js, он же чистый js) - делайте на нем. Хотите сделать отдельное решение на основе какого-либо фреймворка - смотрите, что вам больше нравится и все. Я лично люблю Angular 2/4/5 и делаю, в основном все на нем, однако были проекты и на React, и один на Vue. И ничего плохо не могу сказать про эти фреймворки. Просто каждый берет то, что по душе (если это не прописано в ТЗ=)).

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, на чистом JS я не совсем компетентен создавать подобное, а вот на фреймворке vue все вышло) Cпасибо!